# Perl: Unusual RegExp

Tags: regex, perl

I came across this regexp in a Perl script:

```
$parent_file =~ s@^\Q$CurrentWorkDirForFile\E/@@
```

The current working directory is populated with cwd.

Can anyone please explain what this entry is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In perl, you can use (almost) any character to delimit a regex. So this is equivalent to `s/^\Q$CurrentWorkDirForFile\E///`. The `\Q` and `\E` disable/enable the interpretation of special pattern metacharacters. So, for example, `/\Q+\E/` will match a literal plus even though `+` is a special character in regexps.

Comment: You missed a slash `...\E/@@`, which is probably the reason for the changed delimiters. The regex equivalent is `s/^\Q$CurrentWorkDirForFile\E\///` with a slight "leaning toothpick syndrome."

Comment: Just one extra point: Interpolation happens before the regex is parsed, and more importantly, before `\Q..\E` is performed. That means `\Q..\E` doesn't prevent interpolation, and will affect any interpolated string.